# Lucene fails to add multiple fields with the same FieldType

Tags: java, lucene

While upgrading some legacy code from lucene 3.0.0 to 8.5.2 I've come across a problem with adding fields to an existing doc using a custom FieldType. The snippet below demonstrates the problem:

```java
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.nio.file.Path;
    
    import org.apache.lucene.analysis.en.EnglishAnalyzer;
    import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
    import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
    import org.apache.lucene.document.FieldType;
    import org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader;
    import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexOptions;
    import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
    import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
    import org.apache.lucene.search.IndexSearcher;
    import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
    import org.apache.lucene.store.MMapDirectory;
    
    public class LuceneTest {
        
        private static FieldType FIELD_TYPE = new FieldType();

        static {
            FIELD_TYPE.setStored(true);
            FIELD_TYPE.setTokenized(true);
            FIELD_TYPE.setIndexOptions(IndexOptions.DOCS_AND_FREQS_AND_POSITIONS_AND_OFFSETS);
            FIELD_TYPE.setStoreTermVectors(true);
            FIELD_TYPE.setStoreTermVectorPayloads(true);
            FIELD_TYPE.setStoreTermVectorPositions(true);
            FIELD_TYPE.setStoreTermVectorOffsets(true);
            FIELD_TYPE.freeze();
        }
        
        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
            testLucene();
        }       
            
        public static void testLucene() throws IOException {
            Document doc = new Document();
            doc.add(new Field("f1", "foo", FIELD_TYPE));
            writeDoc(doc);        
            IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(DirectoryReader.open(getDirectory()));
            doc = searcher.doc(0);      
            
            doc.add(new Field("f1", "bar", FIELD_TYPE));
            writeDoc(doc);
        }
    
        private static void writeDoc(Document doc)
                throws IOException {
            Directory directory = getDirectory();
            IndexWriterConfig conf = new IndexWriterConfig(new EnglishAnalyzer());
            IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(directory , conf);
            writer.addDocument(doc);
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();
        }
    
        private static Directory getDirectory() throws IOException {
            return new MMapDirectory(Path.of("lucenttest"));
        }
    }
```

and results in the following exception:

```java
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: all instances of a given field name must have the same term vectors settings (storeTermVectorPositions changed for field="f1")
    at org.apache.lucene.index.TermVectorsConsumerPerField.start(TermVectorsConsumerPerField.java:166)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.TermsHashPerField.start(TermsHashPerField.java:294)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.FreqProxTermsWriterPerField.start(FreqProxTermsWriterPerField.java:72)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain$PerField.invert(DefaultIndexingChain.java:810)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processField(DefaultIndexingChain.java:442)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DefaultIndexingChain.processDocument(DefaultIndexingChain.java:406)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriterPerThread.updateDocument(DocumentsWriterPerThread.java:250)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.updateDocument(DocumentsWriter.java:495)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.updateDocument(IndexWriter.java:1594)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.addDocument(IndexWriter.java:1213)
    at com.profium.sir.LuceneTest.writeDoc(LuceneTest.java:66)
    at com.profium.sir.LuceneTest.testLucene(LuceneTest.java:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runTest(TestCase.java:154)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.junit3.JUnit3TestReference.run(JUnit3TestReference.java:126)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:542)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:770)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:464)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

If the following part is removed from the FieldType it works ok, but removing this from my legacy code causes many tests that depend on positions and offsets to fail.

```java
        FIELD_TYPE.setStoreTermVectorPayloads(true);
        FIELD_TYPE.setStoreTermVectorPositions(true);
        FIELD_TYPE.setStoreTermVectorOffsets(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

The example in the question looks odd because it does the following:

1. It adds a field to the document.
2. It then indexes the document.
3. It then adds a *second* field to the original document, where that second field has the same name as the first field (which in and of itself is not a problem).
4. It then indexes *that same document again* using that second field (using the same field type as the first field).

Looking at the [javadoc](https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_5_2/core/org/apache/lucene/document/Document.html#add-org.apache.lucene.index.IndexableField-) for `Field`'s `add()` methods, it states:

> *Several fields may be added with the same name. In this case, if the fields are indexed, their text is treated as though appended for the purposes of search.*

This means you have not actually added a new field. The new data is appended to the original field's data.

The javadoc goes on to say:

> *Note that add methods only makes sense prior to adding a document to an index. These methods cannot be used to change the content of an existing index! In order to achieve this, a document has to be deleted from an index and a new changed version of that document has to be added.*

The example code adds this second field after the document has been indexed.

Depending on the purpose of these fields, there may be 2 (or more) possibilities:

1. The second field should have been given a different name (`f2`) from the first field.
2. The second field should have been added to a different document (`doc2`).

If you re-arrange the example code for either of these two cases (and to set up all fields prior to indexing a doc), then you will no longer see that error.

I am less familiar with using term vector payloads, positions, and offsets - but I can imagine how adding a second field with the same name on an already indexed document could cause such data to become invalid (hence the error). But I am speculating.

It's possible that earlier versions of Lucene (e.g. 3.0.0) did not handle this situation so well (but that's more speculation).

Here is one of the possible code re-arrangements:

```
    public static void testLucene() throws IOException {
        Document doc = new Document();
        doc.add(new Field("f1", "foo", FIELD_TYPE));
        //writeDoc(doc);

        //Document doc2 = new Document();
        doc.add(new Field("f1", "bar", FIELD_TYPE));
        writeDoc(doc);
        
        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(DirectoryReader.open(getDirectory()));
        Document foundDoc = searcher.doc(0);
    }
```

Looking at the resulting index data using Luke shows the following:

[image]